# Axelar "Transaction Underpriced" Error On Token Deployment For BSC

Tags: blockchain, bsc, axelar

I am getting this error when am trying to deploy token on axelar error come from BSC

`'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":56,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"transaction underpriced"}}\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "transaction underpriced" typically indicates that the gas price set for the transaction is too low. In the context of Axelar, this could mean that the gas payments you've set for the transaction are insufficient.

Axelar's cross-chain transactions are made up of 4 types of costs:

1. Initiating the transaction on the source chain,
2. Processing the transaction through the Axelar blockchain
3. Relaying to the gateway contract on the destination chain
4. Executing the destination smart contract with the payload

The transaction may fail if any of these costs are not adequately covered. For General Message Passing (`callContract` and `callContractWithToken`), a chain-agnostic gas relaying service is implemented to accept gas payments from users on the source chain in its native currency.

If your transaction has stalled, you can use Axelarscan to debug and recover the transaction. Suppose the transaction fails to get executed on the destination chain. In that case, Axelarscan allows you to manually execute a transfer on the destination chain or increase gas payment to the gas receiver on the source chain.

For more details, refer to the **Axelar documentation on transaction recovery** (https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/general-message-passing/recovery).

Please ensure that you have set a sufficient gas price for your transaction. If you continue to experience issues, you may need to debug your contract and make a new call. For more information, you can follow the **Debugging your smart contract guide** (https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/debug/debugging-your-smart-contract).